# Oracle - unable to fetch SUM for suppliers without grn amounts

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have following tables.

Table : grn

```
grn_no | sup_no | amount |

g001   | s001   | 20,000
g002   | s001   | 35,000
g003   | s003   | 15,000
```

Table : supplier

```
sup_no  | sup_name |

s001    | supname1
s002    | supname2
s003    | supname3
```

I want to get sum of amount for **ALL** suppliers, including **NULL** for s003 who does not have grn amount

expected output :

```
s001 | 55,000
s002 | NULL
s003 | 15,000
```

query I tried, but this is not fetching s002 :-

```
 select sup_no, sum(nvl(amount),0)) from grn 
 group by sup_no
```

Comment: Well, if you were a DBMS and someone asked you to return (`select`) records from `grn` table (`from grn`), how would you know that you have to generate rows that are not in the table (for `s002`)? You need to use `supplier left join grn`

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer join:

```
SELECT s.SUP_NO, SUM(g.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT
  FROM SUPPLIER s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN GRN g
    ON g.SUP_NO = s.SUP_NO
  GROUP BY s.SUP_NO
  ORDER BY s.SUP_NO
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/FWGOtVA5)